# Trouble configuring xdebug for PhpStorm on XAMPP for Mac

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

I have followed instructions to install and configure PhpStorm visual debugger for Mac OS, using xdebug.org/wizard.php with the tailored instructions, and worked through every step.

php -v shows:

```
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 23:03:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

in my php.ini (yes I verified this is the correct ini)

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I have restarted Apache since making the changes, and yet when I paste my `phpinfo.php` into the xdebug wizard it analyzes and the summary is as follows:

- Xdebug Installed: no
- Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
- Windows: no
- Zend Server: no
- PHP Version: 5.6.24
- Zend API nr: 220131226
- PHP API nr: 20131226
- Debug Build: no
- Thread Safe Build: no
- Configuration File Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
- Configuration File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
- Extensions directory: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226

EDIT: I have also followed the instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-xdebug.html to configure debugging on in the PhpStorm IDE.

EDIT 2:

my phpinfo():

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
- Loaded Configuration File  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini

EDIT 3:
Link to ENTIRE PhpInfo()
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Fz1a8OLiwRYW1RR0ZnbFVndjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are editing the wrong php.ini then. 1) Please show `phpinfo();` output captured via browser (ideally whole output; otherwise -- xdebug section at very least). 2) Try moving your `zend_extension = ` line out of `[Xdebug]` section.

Comment: P.S. Note that `php -i` shows **different** PHP version than xdebug wizard... which means that you _may be_ editing the wrong php.ini file

Comment: @LazyOne the cli php version is always going to be different than the apache version of php...

Comment: *"the cli php version is always going to be different than the apache version of php"* Nope. This simply means that you have at least 2 different PHP installations on your computer -- one default one and one from XAMPP

Comment: @LazyOne please ignore my previous comment, I added an edit to the post, with the ini location from phpinfo(). My reputation is not good enough yet to post a screenshot, and the phpinfo is very long and looks quite messy posted as text.

Comment: You can post it elsewhere (e.g. Google drive/Dropbox or alike) and share a link.

Comment: @LazyOne hmm, I've worked with PHP for about 8 years and I've always had different versions in the cli than on apache, I've never installed any other version of PHP on this machine, which i recently got and had fresh installs of XAMPP. Not saying you are wrong, just that I've always seen it that way, and was taught those will always be different..

Comment: @LAzyOne would you be ok to move this to chat, or do you not have time? I understand if you are not able, or want to.

Comment: It's quite simple: `which php` .. and it should tell where it is located (the version used in CLI environment). Then compare to what your Apache is using.

Comment: Ahh, you were correct! the cli is pointing to /usr/local/bin/php

Comment: @LazyOne Ahh, you were correct! the cli is pointing to /usr/local/bin/php, does that mean i need to add the xdebug module to that ini?

Comment: No -- that's for CLI. You will only need to add it there if you wish to use it when debugging CLI scripts etc. As for your screenshot -- even though that you have showed only top table (which is like ONLY 3% of the whole output) .. it **clearly** shows that xdebug is NOT enabled there.

Comment: Ok, I will revisit this after the holiday, I just left the office. Thank you for your help, I will post more info when I get back Tuesday, and if you see it awesome if not I'm sure someone will! Thanks again

Comment: @LazyOne - if you are still willing to take a look at my phpinfo, i have edited the post with the new link to the entire phpinfo as you requested. Thanks!

Comment: Saw this? http://jimfrenette.com/2016/03/xdebug-for-xampp-on-os-x/

Comment: Your phpinfo says that debug is disabled, and no debug extension is loaded.

Comment: You can try MAMP. I was always able to debug very quickly with MAMP+PhpStorm.

Comment: @yivi yes I see that debug is disabled, but I'm not sure why? Do i need to add the "xdebug_remote_enable=1" to the ini file used by the CLI?

Comment: What the CLI uses and what XMAPP use are not related. Check the link I sent you earlier, or use MAMP. Easy peasy, and you'll be done much sooner.

Comment: @yivi that link was perfect! Its working like a charm, THANK YOU!! Please upvote my question if you feel I deserve it....I'm brand new on this site and would love to be able to use it again and eventually help others down the road.